# POST request to server gives {} as output in terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I tried connection to database but it has been giving out data as {}, though it is successfully connected and someone told me that error is in my this file, if i want to see what my body parameters it is passing from database then i need to correct this file, so what is that i have to do

```
const connection = require("./model");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const expressHandlebars = require("express-handlebars");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const todolist = require("./routes/todo");

app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "/views"));
app.engine("hbs", expressHandlebars({
    extname: "hbs",
    defaultLayout : "mainlayout",
    layoutsDir : __dirname + "/views/layouts"
}));

app.use("/todo" , todolist );

app.set("view engine", "hbs")
app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
    //res.send("Hello World")
    res.render("index",{})
})

app.listen("2000", () =>{
    console.log("Server Started");
});
```

Comment: Where is the POST end point in this file? What is the POST api you are using?

Comment: Requesting you to bring some sort of clarification in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
//res.send("Hello World")
 res.render("index",{
  title:'index page' 
 })
})

//connection 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`listening on port 
${PORT}`));
```